# Calculated column - Find Multiple Spaces

Tags: 2010, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

A SharePoint list contatins three columns,

- Requestor name (Single Line of Text)
- First name (Calculated column)
- Last Name (Calculated column)

I want to extract First Name and Last Name from the Reequestor Name. The Requestor Name might be in either of the below formats

Sachin Tendulkar or Sachin R Tendulkar

```
   Sachin  | Tendulkar
First Name | Last Name

   Sachin  |      R      | Tendulkar
First Name | Middle Name | Last Name
```

In the First name column, am able to get the required result using below formula,

```
(LEFT( [Requester Name],INT(FIND(" ",[Requester Name])-1))
```

For Last name, I am running into issue here because of the inconsistency in the middle initial. My formula is

```
RIGHT([Calc Column Last Name],LEN([Calc Column Last Name])-INT(FIND(" ",[Calc Column Last Name])))
```

Doesnt like the fact that if there is a middle initial. If there is a middle initial,  I get a #VALUE! error.

How can I just extract the last name?

Thank you!

Comment: How does the name field get populated, does it auto fill from User Profile or do users actually enter in their name?

Comment: Your second formula is reading from the calculated colum?

Comment: @Ramana - Its auto populated from AD.

Comment: @Amal - yes. I have a typo in my question. The issue is when there is a middle name, I get #VALUE! error.

Comment: @Shaji So you have a Full Name field in your form that gets auto populated by AD? Do you have some sort of Javascript that does this currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider Requester Name field contais value as **Nagarajan Muthukumar**

Formula for First name: `(LEFT([Requester Name],INT(FIND(" ",[Requester Name])-1)))`

Result in First Name: **Nagarajan**

Formula for Last name: `RIGHT([Requester Name],LEN([Requester Name])-INT(FIND(" ",[Requester Name])))`

Result in Last Name: **Muthukumar**

If the Name is **Nagarajan M Muthukumar** (with initial), by the above formula am getting Last Name as **M Muthukumar**

The below formula will be a overall consolidated formula for both name with and without initial,

- It gives the Last Name as **Muthukumar** if the Name is **Nagarajan M
  Muthukumar** (With Initial)
- It also gives the Last Name as **Muthukumar** if the Name is **Nagarajan    Muthukumar** (Without Initial)

Is this what expected?

`=IF(IFERROR(FIND(" ",RIGHT([Requester Name],LEN([Requester Name])-INT(FIND(" ",[Requester Name])))),"0")="0",RIGHT([Requester Name],LEN([Requester Name])-INT(FIND(" ",[Requester Name]))),RIGHT(RIGHT([Requester Name],LEN([Requester Name])-INT(FIND(" ",[Requester Name]))),LEN(RIGHT([Requester Name],LEN([Requester Name])-INT(FIND(" ",[Requester Name]))))-INT(FIND(" ",RIGHT([Requester Name],LEN([Requester Name])-INT(FIND(" ",[Requester Name])))))))`

Comment: I am using the exact same query. The problem is: what if your name has a middle initial?

Comment: Updated the answer, please check and tell

Comment: Merci! Works like a charm.