# Is there a way to remove white-space from the Text?

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, column-validation

For example,

If I give input text in the Column as - **mo bi le  pho  ne**.

Then the data should be saved in the column as- **mobilephone** (it should remove all the white-spaces)

Also, the Validation formula  **=ISERROR(FIND(" ",NoSpace))** doesn't work in SharePoint Online.
Means while editing an item (NoSpace column) the error shows up. But when creating an item by filling up text in the NoSpace column the error doesn't shows up and the record is not created.

Could you please help me on this?

Thank You.

Comment: Check [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/185137/calculated-column-find-multiple-spaces) if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try with semicolon

```
=ISERROR(FIND(" ";NoSpace))
```

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint column function does not have something like `SUBSTITUTE()` in Excel. You will need to use `=FIND()` and `=REPLACE()` to replace `=SUBSTITUTE()`.

And if the white space does not have a static position and there will be multiple white spaces, the column will be quite awful as you need to get the index, nested structure will be essential and it is not certain we can get a global formula to do this.